# Binary Tree - Among the furthest from root, furthest to the right

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a binary tree. Amongst all the furthest nodes from the root (Height of the tree I believe), I need to find the furthest to the right of those nodes.

Example 1:

```
      M
     / \
    G   N
   / \   \
  D   H   O
 / \       \
B   F       Q
```

The furthest to the right amongst the furthest nodes from the root is 'Q'.

Example 2:

```
      M
     / \
    G   N
   / \   \
  D   H   O
 / \       
B   F
```

The furthest to the right amongst the furthest nodes from the root is 'F'.

The code I have can get deepest node and return the rightmost node (left if deepest node has no right children). But then I ran into a issue where there could be leaves of the same size and I didn't know how to back track and compare all of them to find the furtherest (which in this case would be 'Q')

I found out how to find the max height of the tree, but not how to implement that into my code

This is what I have thus far:

```
public void find(Node<T> r) {   

    if(r.right == null) { // Are there any children to the right?
        if(r.left.size() > 1) {
            find(r.left); // If not, we go left if there are more than 1
        }

        if(r.left.size() == 1) { //
            rNode = r.left.data;
        }

    }

    if(r.left == null) { // Are there any children to the left?
        if(r.right.size() > 1) {
            find(r.right); // If not, we go right if there are more than 1
        }

        if(r.right.size() == 1) {
            rNode = r.right.data; // If the right is the only node left, pick it as the answer
        }
    }

    if(r.left != null && r.right != null) { // Are there children to the left and right?
        if(r.left.size() == r.right.size()) { // 
            if(r.left.size() == 1) { // If we have 1 child to the right and left, pick the right child
                rNode = r.left.data; // If the left is the only node left, pick it as the answer
            } 
        }

        if(r.left.size() > r.right.size()) { // Are there more to the left?
            find(r.left); // Proceed
        }

        if(r.left.size() < r.right.size()) { // Are there more to the right?
            find(r.right); // Proceed
        }
    } 

}

public int maxDepth(Node<T> r) {

     if(r == null){
         return 0;
     }

     int leftDepth = maxDepth(r.left);
     int rightDepth = maxDepth(r.right);

     return Math.max(leftDepth, rightDepth)+1;     
 }


/**
 * Among all the nodes which are farthest from the root, find the one which is
 * farthest to the right.
 * 
 * @return data value of said node
 */
public T findRightmostLowest() {
    if(root.size() == 1) return root.data;

    find(root);
    return rNode;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to backtrack?  I'd argue that if Q or O have left leaves, Q is still furthest to the right.

Comment: @markspace I suppose I don't, but I'm not really sure how to go about getting the correct solution

Comment: First clarify what you really want.  The "furthest to the right" is the greatest (largest) value in the tree.  If that's what you want, then it's Q, with no backtracking needed.

Comment: If you want the furthest to the right, why bother going left at all? Just keep going right until you can't anymore.

Comment: @markspace It’s the furthest to the right amongst the furthest from the root. So in this case it’s B, F, and Q. And Q is to the right among them, I tried to clarify it in there but my teacher has a way with making bizarre assignments.

Comment: Your teacher should clarify, yes.  However there's only one furthest to the right, so I guess your teacher really means furthest from the root.  That'll require a full tree search.  Look up "in order" or "pre order" or "post order" for trees.

Comment: @markspace It's not just that, I'll put another example. It's the furthest nodes from the root, and the rightmost between those nodes.

Comment: Re. your second example: you can't sort (choose) between two criteria at the same time.  You have to pick one that "goes first."  In your second example, B and F are both furthest from the root, so that's obviously the main sorting criteria.  Between them, F is further to the right (not furthest) so choose F.  But you need to find furthest from the root first, then select between those.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help, it guided me to the correct solution:

```
T rNode = null;
boolean found = false;

/**
 * Helper method that recursively finds Rightmost node between 
 * the nodes farthest from the root
 * 
 * @param r
 * @param depth
 * @param i - Our current level of the tree
 */
public void find(Node<T> r, int depth, int i) { 
    if(i == depth && found == false) { // Are we at the answer?
        rNode = r.data; // Dump node into our temporary node

        found = true;   // Change  found to true so we don't enter 
                        // the check a second time.
    }

    if(r.right != null) { // Are there children to the right?
        // If there is, does it lead to one of the farthest leaves?
        if((maxDepth(r.right) + i) == depth) {
            find(r.right, depth, i + 1); 
        }
    }

    if(r.left != null) { // Are there children to the left?
        // If there is, does it lead to one of the farthest leaves?
        if((maxDepth(r.left) + i) == depth) { 
            find(r.left, depth, i + 1);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Find the height to our tree.
 * 
 * @param r
 * @return
 */
public int maxDepth(Node<T> r) {

     if(r == null){
         return 0;
     }

     int leftDepth = maxDepth(r.left);
     int rightDepth = maxDepth(r.right);

     return Math.max(leftDepth, rightDepth)+1;     
 }


/**
 * Among all the nodes which are farthest from the root, find the one which is
 * farthest to the right.
 * 
 * @return data value of said node
 */
public T findRightmostLowest() {

    rNode = null; // Reset the temporary node
    found = false; // Reset our boolean variable for helper method

    if(root.size() == 1) return root.data; // If tree has only 1 data point, return it

    find(root, maxDepth(root), 1); // Jump into the helper method

    return rNode; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tree problem almost always have as recursive as non recursive solutions. And usually, recursive one is much simplier. If it is OK for the problem, then it could look like this one:

```
public static <T> Node<T> getRootFurthest(Node<T> root) {
    return findFurthest(root, 0, new NodeDepth<>()).node;
}

private static <T> NodeDepth<T> findFurthest(Node<T> node, int depth, NodeDepth<T> furthest) {
    if (node == null)
        return furthest;

    // >= - rigth node of equal depth
    // >  - left node of equal depth
    if (depth >= furthest.depth) {
        furthest.node = node;
        furthest.depth = depth;
    }

    findFurthest(node.left, depth + 1, furthest);
    findFurthest(node.right, depth + 1, furthest);

    return furthest;
}
```

And two supported class declarations:

```
private static final class NodeDepth<T> {

    private Node<T> node;
    private int depth = -1;
}

public static class Node<T> {

    private T val;
    private Node<T> left;
    private Node<T> right;
}
```